# How to make a div containing links non-clickable based on its class

Tags: jquery, html, css

These are the previous and next buttons html code what i want to do is to disable them when another button called filter is clicked and further if some conditions are satisfied

```
 <div class="page-btn" id="page-next"><a href="testlink/index/3/1"><div class="pbtn-txt" style="color: whitesmoke;">Next </div></a></div>  

 <div class="page-btn" id="page-previous"><a href="testlink/index/3/1"><div class="pbtn-txt" style="color: whitesmoke;">previous </div></a></div>
```

How can I disable them based on some condition? the links are generated at runtime. for example

```
$('.filter').click(function(){

                    if(condition) {
        disable next links click using class page-btn;
        disable prev links click using class page-btn;
                    } 

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code checks the class of the link when clicked:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {    
        $('.filter').on('click', function(){
            if(condition)
               $(".page-btn a").attr('href', 'javascript:void(0);');
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: This is really clumsy and will also not work in case that there are several classes like `class="class1 class2 filter"`... Using [.hasClass("filter")](http://api.jquery.com/hasClass/) will make it work but it will still be very clumsy.

See my answer.

Comment: thanks but it would be great if you could get the exact opposite of your answer. please read my re-edited question. believe you might know the answer.

Comment: Welcome! Im glad I cold be a help!

Comment: is there a way to re-enable the disabled links ?

Comment: yes, on what event do you want to re-enable the links?

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.filter').click(function(){
     return false;
});
```

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/JbSU6/5/)

**Edit:**

If the classes change dynamically, this is a better approach that will support it:

```
$(document).on("click", ".filter",
    function () {
        return false;
    });
```

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/JbSU6/6/)

**Edit 2:**

After you've described your problem better, this is probably what you're looking for:

```
$('.filter').click(function(){

      if (condition) {
          $(".page-btn a").click(
              function () { return false; }
          );
      } 
});
```

Comment: as you see previous and next are links within a div which i will show like buttons, i want to disable them based on some condition is that possible?

Comment: It sounds like it's possible but you have to give us more details. Such as what is the condition, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Or You could use

```
$('.filter').click(function(e){
                if(condition) {
                  e.preventDefault();
                } 
});
```